# Корректный способ повесить onclick для toggleclass на пункт разнородного многоуровневого меню в react js

Tags: reactjs

Привет!
Есть ли корректный способ построить многоуровневое разнородное 1 компонентное меню без вынесения пунктов в массив и без цикла, с последующей привязкой к пунктам пеню onclick для динамического удаления/добавления класса, при этом на текущем элементе должен быть toggleClass а на остальных этот класс должен удаляться, насколько такое решение корректно в плане архитектуры react и какие могут быть альтернативы?Полезной для себя инфы не нашел.В голову приходить решения записать например data-id каждого пункта в массив,и при каждом клике искать присутсвие data-id по indexOf.но думаю должно быть какое то другое решение.
Меню такого типа:

```html
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<span>Текст</span>
<div>
    Текст
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <div>
        <a>6</a>
        <a>7</a>
        Текст
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Одна из основных идей React (как и других подобных решений вроде Angular и Vue) - это минимизировать манипулирование DOM напрямую, замени манипуляции с DOM на манипуляции с данными. Если вам нужно манипулировать DOM напрямую React вам не помощник.

В итоге: если вы хотите использовать React (или angular или Vue) для прямого манипулирования DOM, то React вам просто не нужен. Подключите тот же jQuery: с ним вам будет работать гораздо удобнее и код получится лучше.

Если же у вас уже есть приложение на React, где React используется как надо, но есть конкретно эта задача, где необходима прямая манипуляцию DOM, то опять таки, в подключении jQuery нет ничего страшного. Сделайте эту часть приложения на jQuery или даже через манипуляции DOM через встроенное API DOM элементов.